# Where to ask about Legal History, Roman Law and Comparative Law

Tags: discussion, support, scope, tags, asking-questions

I want to ask about the Civil Legal System and its 2 subgroups.

Napoleonic and Germanistic.

I am thinking of the tags History, Legal-History, Civil-Legal-System, Comparative-Law.

Answer (score 1):

Ask on https://law.stackexchange.com/ or https://history.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Would it be considered too broad or multiple questions at once? My question is about the Napoleonic and Germanistic subgroups but Roman law is the preliminary/subsidiary issue. If one affirms that the Germanistic subgroup is more similar to the latter/final days of the Empire's law while the Napoleonic more similar to the earlier days I need to know the legal difference between those 2.

Comment: Best to ask one at a time. You can ask several at once or you can wait on answers before asking the next.

Comment: So it will be in fact considered 2 separate questions.

Comment: If you ask several questions at once, it is likely that the question will be closed as too broad. The more questions you pack into one post, the less coherent your question and the answers will be.

Comment: @user6726 I was asking exactly that(whether they would be considered two separate questions) because to me they are preliminary/supplementary issues.